# How to attach multiple files in a visualforce page like as in gmail

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, attachment

Attach file button should have the capability adding multiple files at a time and deleting one among the uploaded files. Just like we have this in gmail.

Right now, I have ability to upload a single attachment to the parent id. Looking for uploading multiple attachments.

Comment: Hi venky, I didn't vote you down, but you might want to take a moment to revisit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Use the script on this blog to bypass the limit http://kevansfdc.blogspot.com/2017/05/upload-attachment-to-salesforce-without.html